# Is it possible to specify the general solution $(\ldots,u_{-1},u_0,u_1,\ldots)$ of $\ddot{u}_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n+1}-2u_n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In more detail: Let $I\subset\mathbb R$ be on open interval and let $D$ be the set of all twice differentiable functions from $I$ to $\mathbb C$:
\begin{equation}
D:=\left\{f\colon I\to\mathbb C:f\text{ is twice differentiable}\right\}
\end{equation}
My goal is to determine the following set:
\begin{align}
\left\{u\colon\mathbb Z\to D:\ddot{u}_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n+1}-2u_n\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb Z\right\}
\end{align}
**Observations**:
If $\ddot{u}_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n+1}-2u_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$, then $u_n\in C^{\infty}$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. This means that it suffices to determine the set
\begin{align}
X:=\left\{u\colon\mathbb Z\to C^{\infty}:\ddot{u}_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n+1}-2u_n\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb Z\right\}
\end{align}
$X$ is vector space.

**Motivation:** That is the differential equation one needs to solve in the case of a infinite chain of masses, where the acceleration of one specific mass at the time $t$ depends only on the distance to its neighbours at that time. More precisely, one needs to solve $m\ddot{u}_n=C(u_{n-1}-u_n)+C(u_{n+1}-u_n)$.

Comment: Can't you choose arbitrary $C^\infty$ $u_0, u_1$ and then run the recurrence relation in both directions to define $u_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$? e.g., once you have $u_0$ and $u_1$ you can define $u_2(t)=2u_1(t)+u_1''(t)-u_0(t)$, etc...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I have to try it out, but I think that's a great idea!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Is my answer what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v,w\in C^{\infty}$, there is exactly one $u\in X$ with $u_0=v$ and $u_1=w$.
(Simply set $u_{n+1}=\ddot{u}_n+2u_n-u_{n-1}$ for $1\leq n$ and $u_{n-1}=\ddot{u}_n+2u_n-u_{n+1}$ for $n\leq0$.)

Let $u(v,w)$ be the element of $X$ described above, then $X=\left\{u(v,w):v,w\in C^{\infty}\right\}$.